# Generate a Bounded Cumulative Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to replicate an Excel sheet with a simple conditional in a cumulative formula using Power BI

In Excel, this is easily handled to generate

```
some_param  1
bound_min   0
bound_max  10

measure1           = raw_data1 - raw_data2 +some_param
bounded_cumulative = if cumulative < bound_min then bound_min else
                        if cumulative > bound_max then bound_max else
                            cumulative

date          raw_data1    raw_data2  measure1 bounded_cumulative 
1/01/2022          7          9         -1          0   (-1 < bound_min = 0)
2/01/2022          5          1          5          5   (0 + 5 = 5)
3/01/2022          1         10         -8          0   (5 - 8 < bound_min = 0)
4/01/2022          9          9          1          1   (0 + 1 = 1)
5/01/2022          7          8          0          1   (1 + 0 = 1)
6/01/2022         10          2          9         10   (1 + 9 = 10)
7/01/2022          9          6          4         10   (10 + 4 > bound_max = 10)
8/01/2022          6          5          2         10   (10 + 2 > bound_max = 10)
9/01/2022          4         10         -5          5   (10 - 5 = 5)
10/01/2022         4          4          1          6   (.............
11/01/2022        10          6          5         10
12/01/2022         9          1          9         10
13/01/2022         4          1          4         10
14/01/2022         9          4          6         10
```

Cumulative is only increased or decreased if it is between the bounds. Anything outside the bounds is ignored.

In Power BI DAX I've got

```
    bounded_cumulative = 
    VAR cumulative = [cumulative]
    VAR MaxBound = [bound_max Value]
    VAR MinBound = [bound_min Value]
    RETURN
    IF (
        cumulative <= MinBound,
        MinBound,
        IF ( cumulative >= MaxBound, MaxBound, cumulative )
    )
```

Which almost what I'm after.

[Sample Excel sheet and Power BI Report here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vmm0i3l4lw1ug0/cumulative_bounded.zip?dl=0)